# Topological Sort in Java

Tags: java, graph, topological-sort

I'm trying to implement topological sort for a graph of characters.

Here's my code.

```
public class Graph {

    private int vertices;
    private HashMap<Character, LinkedList<Character>> adjList;
    private boolean isDirected;

    public Graph(int vertices){
        this.vertices = vertices;
        adjList = new HashMap<>();
        isDirected = true;
    }

    public void addEdge(Character from, Character to){

        if(adjList.containsKey(from)){
            LinkedList<Character> l = adjList.get(from);
            l.add(to);
        }else{
            LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
            l.add(to);
            adjList.put(from, l);
        }
    }

    public Deque<Character> topologicalSort(){
        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Set<Character> visited = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator itr = adjList.entrySet().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
            LinkedList<Character> l = (LinkedList<Character>) pair.getValue();
            ListIterator<Character> litr = l.listIterator();
            while(litr.hasNext()){
                Character key = (Character)litr.next();
                if(visited.contains(key)) continue;
                else{
                    topSortUtil(key, stack, visited);

                }
            }
        }
            return stack;

    }

    public void topSortUtil(Character key, Deque<Character> stack, Set<Character> visited){
        visited.add(key);
        LinkedList<Character> list = adjList.get(key);
        ListIterator<Character> litr = list.listIterator();
        while(litr.hasNext()){
            Character childKey = (Character) litr.next();
            if(visited.contains(childKey)) continue;
            else topSortUtil(childKey,stack, visited);
        }
        stack.offerFirst(key);
    }




}
```

The client code that I'm using to test is as follows,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Graph graph = new Graph(5);
        graph.addEdge('a', 'b');
        graph.addEdge('a', 'c');
        graph.addEdge('a', 'd');
        graph.addEdge('b', 'd');
        graph.addEdge('b', 'e');
        graph.addEdge('c', 'e');

        Deque<Character> stack = graph.topologicalSort();
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that I don't get any output on the console. Can't seem to figure out what the bug is. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug with a very small `Graph`?

Comment: Yup, the code's breaking at the util function, but can't seem to understand why.

Comment: How does that break? The `topSortUtil` is only used by `topSortUtil` itself. Your code can never reach it.

Comment: Your stack from Main class is empty, that's why. Method 'topologicalSort' just initialize empty stack and returning it. Methond 'topSortUtil' is never used.

Comment: Amended that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is crashing at `topSortUtil` because `LinkedList<Character> list = adjList.get(key);` is being called when `key='d'`. Since `d` has no outgoing edges, `list` is `null`, so when you get to this line `ListIterator<Character> litr = list.listIterator();`, you're calling a method on `null`, which throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `topSortUtil` method to something like this =>

```
public void topSortUtil(Character key, Deque<Character> stack, Set<Character> visited){
    visited.add(key);
    ListIterator<Character> litr ;

    LinkedList<Character> list = adjList.get(key);
    if(list!=null) //null check
    {
    litr = list.listIterator();

    while(litr.hasNext()){
        Character childKey = (Character) litr.next();
        if(visited.contains(childKey)) continue;
        else topSortUtil(childKey,stack, visited);
    }
    }

    stack.offerFirst(key);
}
```